# Symfony 2.8 FosUserBundle User Locale Internacionalization doesn`t work

Tags: php, symfony, session, fosuserbundle

I create my app with **Symfony 2.8** and **FosUserBundle**. I wiew a lot of tutorials and I don´t understand why it does not take the value of the user session.

I do it like the example in the web of symfony: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/session/locale_sticky_session.html

The configuration of the first Event Listener is correct but the second event Listener **doesn't set the local value in session**

```
<?php
//AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need

        $locale = $request->getLocale();
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        var_dump($locale);

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/..'),
        ));
        /*return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ));*/
    }
}
```

Event Listeners:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/EventListener/LocaleListener.php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'en')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
        if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered after the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 15)),
        );
    }
}
```

UserLocaleListener.php

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/EventListener/UserLocaleListener.php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

/**
 * Stores the locale of the user in the session after the
 * login. This can be used by the LocaleListener afterwards.
 */
class UserLocaleListener
{
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $session;

    public function __construct(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event
     */
    public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        if (null !== $user->getLocale()) {
            $this->session->set('_locale', $user->getLocale());
        }
    }
}
```

The configuration of config.yml is:

```
parameters:
    locale: en
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
    resetting:
        email:
            from_email:
                address:        manuelterronalvarez@gmail.com
                sender_name:    App Resetting

jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: "%locale%"
    locales: [es, en]
    strategy: prefix_except_default
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance